# show static ad space only for large screen in materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

part one is responsive but ad space is not responsive here. then how to show this ad-space?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col s12 m12 l10">
    <!--part one-->
 </div>
 <div class="hide-on-med-and-down showAdPart">
    <!-- 300x600 ad space--> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to spasific the responsive `col-md-6` -- for example

Comment: i have set the part one as l10 class this have 83% width but when i resize the static ad was goes outer side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use l12 class for 100% or your width and follow like,

```
 <div class="col s12 m12 l12 partOne">
    <!--part one-->
 </div>
 <div class="hide-on-med-and-down showAdPart">
    <!-- 300x600 ad space--> 
 </div>
```

css : use calc()

```
@media screen and (min-width: 993px){   /* large screen */
  .partOne.col.l12{
      width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
      width:    -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
      width:         calc(100% - 300px);
 }
}
```